# Difference visibility in subquery join and where

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I had problems with a simple join:

```
SELECT * 
FROM worker wo
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT wp.id_working_place
    FROM working_place wp 
    JOIN working_place_worker wpw ON ( wp.id_working_place = wpw.id_working_place
        AND wpw.id_worker = wo.id_worker)
)
```

The error I had was `ORA-00904: "WO"."ID_WORKER": not valid identifier`.

Then I decided to move the union of tables from `join` clause to the `where` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM worker wo
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT wp.id_working_place
    FROM working_place wp 
    JOIN working_place_worker wpw ON ( wp.id_working_place = wpw.id_working_place)
    WHERE wpw.id_worker = wo.id_worker
)
```

And this last query `works` perfect.

Why is not possible to make it in the `join`? The table should be visible like it is in the `where` clause. Am I missing something?

Comment: A JOIN clause is more specific than a WHERE clause: it specifies how to join the next table to the preceding tables in the FROM clause. There is no column `WO.ID_WORKER` in the FROM clause of the subquery.

Comment: @TonyAndrews Can you give a reference to a product and/or standard limitation of columns in ON or even in correlated queries? Because in eg MySQL & the 200n standards I see no limits & semantically there aren't either.

Comment: @philipxy: See [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/queries006.htm#SQLRF30046): "To execute a join of three or more tables, Oracle first joins two of the tables based on the join conditions comparing their columns and then joins the result to another table based on join conditions containing columns of the joined tables and the new table. Oracle continues this process until all tables are joined into the result."

Comment: the same sort of error is generated in MySQL by the attempt to correlate through join 
"Unknown column 'wo.id_worker' in 'on clause': ..." 
whereas Oracle uses 
"ORA-00904: "WO"."ID_WORKER": invalid identifier : 

The table alias "wo" is not available in the self-contained FROM clause of the subquery, but is available in the WHERE clause of that subquery because WHERE must permit correlations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In

```
FROM working_place wp 
JOIN working_place_worker wpw ON ... 
WHERE ...
```

the `ON` clause refers *only* to the two tables participating in the join, namely `wp` and `wpw`.  Names from the outer query are not visible to it.

The `WHERE` clause (and its cousin `HAVING` is the means by which the outer query is correlated to the subquery.  Names from the outer query *are* visible to it.

To make it easy to remember,

- ON is about the JOIN, how two tables relate to form a row (or rows)
- WHERE is about the selection criteria, the test the rows must pass

While the SQL parser will admit literals (which aren't column names) in the ON clause, it draws the line at references to columns outside the join.  You could regard this as a favor that guards against errors.

In your case, the `wo` table is not part of the `JOIN`, and is rejected.  It *is* part of the whole query, and is recognized by `WHERE`.