# Sub-query refers to super-query's column, different behavior between where and join

Tags: mysql

Here is a strange thing which has confused me. It is not about business logic, but about SQL syntax, or at least I suppose it is.

I have created a table and filled it with data like below:

```
create table test (
   col1 int,
   col2 int
);

insert into test values
(1, 1),
(2, 2),
(3, 3);
```

When I execute the query

```
select *
from test t1
where exists(
    select 1
    from test t2
    join test t3
    on t2.col1 = t3.col1
    where t2.col2 = t1.col2
);
```

it yields the following result ([SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e488d/3)):

```
| col1 | col2 |
|------|------|
|    1 |    1 |
|    2 |    2 |
|    3 |    3 |
```

This is definitely right.

Then I changed `where` in the sub-query to `and`:

```
select *
from test t1
where exists(
    select 1
    from test t2
    join test t3
    on t2.col1 = t3.col1
    and t2.col2 = t1.col2
);
```

This produces the following error ([SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e488d/4)):

> Unknown column 't1.col2' in 'on clause'

I've searched for the reason for a long while and cannot figure it out.

I hope somebody can take me away from this confusion. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Parent col is visible to sub-SQL where; your second SQL: sub-SQL join cannot use parent col in join-on condition: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24188292/difference-visibility-in-subquery-join-and-where

Comment: @SIDU Thanks for the link, any more details about mysql official docs?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a syntax error. The alias t1 exists in the "outer query". Only the WHERE clause or HAVING clause allows you to refer to an outer query (and when doing this you form a "correlated" subquery).

The JOIN is not able to refer to the outer query (i.e. that join can only refer to table aliases t2 and t3 as it can only refer to aliases in the "inner" query)

```
-- the "Outer query" is:
select *
from test t1

-- the "inner query" is:
select 1
from test t2
join test t3
on t2.col1 = t3.col1
```

You introduce a "correlation" in the where clause by referring to alias t1

```
select *
from test T1
where exists(
    select 1
    from test t2
    join test t3
    on t2.col1 = t3.col1
    where t2.col2 = T1.col2
);
```